# I am trying to make my own module and I want to show the users a help for the module functions

Tags: python, function

I am creating a module in which I'm defining multiple functions and I want to give the users some help regarding it, just like the help() function does. Still, I'm not quite sure how I do that, so can someone help me with it, for example, if I want help regarding this function, what will I have to do?

```
def shanky_calculate_average(*args):
    my_average  = sum(args) / len(args)
    return my_average
```

I just want to know if I can get help in the same way as you can on things like help(pandas.read_excel)

Answer (score 0):

What help() actually does is printing the function name with arguments and its *docstring*. Docstrings are comments directly after the function or class definition and are declared using either '''triple single quotes''' or """triple double quotes""".

So doing something like this:

```
def shanky_calculate_average(*args):
    '''
       Computes the average of the arguments.
       Example: shanky_calculate_average(1,2,3,4)
    '''
    my_average  = sum(args) / len(args)
    return my_average
```

will result in `help(shanky_calculate_average)`
to print

```
shanky_calculate_average(*args)
    Computes the average of the arguments.
    Example: shanky_calculate_average(1,2,3,4)
```

As a sidenote, you can also access docstrings via the `__doc__` property of the object like this: `shanky_calculate_average.__doc__`.